# Glide FileNotFoundException: No content provider when loading images from internet

Tags: android, rest, android-glide

I made my own rest api and now it just has endpoint where I show some images. Here how it looks in spring boot application

```
@GetMapping("/image/{name:.+}")
    public byte[] getImage(@PathVariable(value = "name") String name) {
        return storageService.loadFileAsByteArray(name);
    }
```

and this is storage service method

```
 public byte[] loadFileAsByteArray(String filename) {
            Resource resource = loadFile(filename);
            try {
                return IOUtils.toByteArray(resource.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

and here what I do in my android app

```
Glide.with(context!!.applicationContext).load("http://myipaddress/api/image/myimage.jpg").into(it)
```

So here what I get from glide

Root cause (2 of 2)

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://myipaddress/api/image/myimage.jpg
                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1112)
                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:964)
                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:887)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:22)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:13)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:299)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:394)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:119)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:151)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:142)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:65)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:97)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:148)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:142)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:65)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:97)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:299)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:269)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:230)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
```

but if i go to that link in my browser everything just works. Why this is happening?

Comment: Same Glide 4.7.1. No images loading due to "No content provider ...". Switched from WIFI to Mobile. All images load fine (~25). Switched back to WIFI again. One image loads. All subsequent attempts result in: "No content provider ..."

Comment: this error exists on latest version 4.7.1. you can track & comment about this issue on https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2894

Answer (score 6):

If you are targeting API 28 on and the issue appears on Android 9 and the URL starting with `http` your issue is with cleartext traffic 
as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) in Network security configuration

> Starting with Android 9.0 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.
>
> ensure that all connections to are always done over HTTPS to protect
>   sensitive traffic from hostile networks.

If you want to Opt out of cleartext traffic

**Add this property on your application manifests only**

```
<application
 . 
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
 .

 >

 </application>
```

And if you want to have specific domains to have the rule

Create file res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">secure.example.com</domain>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add to gradle `annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'`

Comment: this is not an answer