# Picasso doesn't load view in MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I'm doing a basic Android Studio Project for loading a URL into an ImageView using Picasso with Kotlin. I have followed every step from the official webpage of Picasso, but when I run my app the emulator shows an empty view.

In my Gradle I added the implementation of Picasso:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

And Internet permission within manifest tag too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And in `MainActivity` the basic use of Picasso:

```
Picasso.get().load("http://paproject.online/hp.jpg").into(imageTest)
```

`imageTest` is the id of a `Imageview` with `layout_height = 200dp` and `layout_weight = 200dp`.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54094950/3321991

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Your Photo size is too big so in `ImageView` tag in `XML` Edit `layout_width` and `layout_height` to Const Size Like 100dp.

and If U can Change Picasso with [Glide](http://sjudd.github.io/glide/). maybe Can help you

Comment: I'm trying Picasso because Glide didn't work me at the first time too.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is larger (1024x768) than your ImageView, but of course that should not be a reason for you to get blank. Try as below which also includes local image resource nopic for the error cases. Seems you have the correct include

```
// Lazy load the image with Picasso
get()
        .load(yourURL)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.nopic)
        .error(R.drawable.nopic)
        .into(img);
```

Comment: Ok, I just added what you told me and now is loading the drawable that is place in placeholder instead of the URL image. In my Logcat doesn't appear any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your image before including it into imageView

```
Picasso  
.with(context)
.load("http://paproject.online/hp.jpg")
.resize(200, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions.
.into(imageViewResize);
```

Or you can use any cropping technique like .CenterCrop(). 
You can read more about this https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

Comment: I prove all you say but still having an empty view.

Comment: You can activate the logs by calling .setLoggingEnabled(true) on your Picasso instance and view all Picasso request on Android logcat

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is already solve. It seems that there is a problem loading images in Android 9.0. So the solution is in this link: [Picasso image loading issue with Android 9.0 Pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139689/picasso-image-loading-issue-with-android-9-0-pie).
Thanks to everyone for your responses.